# Block not available (pruned data)

Tags: bitcoin

```
# bitcoin-cli getblockhash 277136
00000000000000027ea588641dbb07b857900a25e05797c6be40c774de2128b7
# bitcoin-cli getblock 00000000000000027ea588641dbb07b857900a25e05797c6be40c774de2128b7

error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Block not available (pruned data)"}
```

I would like information about this block.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core 23.0.0 introduced [`getblockfrompeer`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/24.0.0/rpc/blockchain/getblockfrompeer/) which gives you the ability to

> Attempt to fetch block from a given peer.

So

```bash
bitcoin-cli getblockfrompeer 00000000000000027ea588641dbb07b857900a25e05797c6be40c774de2128b7 0
```

should solve your problem.